# Maven: Finding out whether running in a 32 or a 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, maven-2, jvm, maven

How can I enable or disable a maven profile based on whether the VM that is executing maven is a 32 bit or a 64 bit JVM ?

I tried this:

```xml
<activation>
   <os>
       <arch>x86</arch>
   </os>
 </activation>
```

or `amd64` respectively to detect a 32/64 bit VM, but this fails on a 32 bit VM running on a 64 bit Windows as it activates the 64 bit profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Sun VM,
check for the system property `sun.arch.data.model`

```xml
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>32bitstuff</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>sun.arch.data.model</name>
      <value>32</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>64bitstuff</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>sun.arch.data.model</name>
      <value>64</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
</profile>

</profiles>
```

**Reference:**

- [HotSpot FAQ](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/HotSpotFAQ.html)